# product of two functions

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-3.x

I have two functions, `f` and `g`. Both have the same signature: `(x)`. I want to create a new function, `z`, with the same signature:

```
def z(x):
  return f(x) * g(x)
```

except that I'd like to be able to write

`z = f * g` instead of the above code. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think so - operators aren't defined for function arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The funny thing is that it is quite possible. I made a project some days ago to do things like that.

Here it is: [FuncBuilder](https://github.com/jbvsmo/funcbuilder/blob/master/funcbuilder.py)

By now you can only define variables, but you can use my metaclass with the help of some other functions to build a class to what you want.

Problems:

- It's slow
- It's really slow
- You think you want that but describing functions the way they meant to be described is the right way.

You should use your first code.

Just as a proof of concept:

```
from funcbuilder import OperatorMachinery

class FuncOperations(metaclass=OperatorMachinery):
     def __init__(self, function):
          self.func = function
     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

def func(self, *n, oper=None):
    if not n:
        return type(self)(lambda x: oper(self.func(x)))
    return type(self)(lambda x: oper(self.func(x), n[0](x)))

FuncOperations.apply_operators([func, func])
```

Now you can code like that:

```
@FuncOperations
def f(x):
    return x + 1

@FuncOperations
def g(x):
    return x + 2
```

And the desired behavior is:

```
>>> z = f * g
>>> z(3)
20
```

---

I added a better version of it on the [FuncBuilder](https://github.com/jbvsmo/funcbuilder/blob/master/funcbuilder.py) project. It works with any operation between a `FuncOperation` object and another callable. Also works on unary operations. :D

You can play with it to make functions like:

```
z = -f + g * h
```

Comment: I started hacking a class together to prove to myself it could be done rather easily, but this is much more elegant, very nice :)

Comment: I am using your idea in my project, and it works great so far. I didn't use metaclass though. What's the advantage of the metaclasses vs. simply defining all the operators you need in `FuncOperations`? (I posted some sample code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839288/higher-order-functions-automatic-generation-vs-manual-definition).)

Comment: @max I like metaclasses because it's not much work to extend the code later (Just like I did above to create the new behavior for functions). But feel free to work with the things you're already used to because creating metaclasses may be a little hard in the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

Something close *is* possible:

```
z = lambda x: f(x) * g(x)
```

Personally, I find this way more intuitive than `z = f * g`, because mathematically, multiplying functions doesn't mean anything. Depending on the interpretation of the `*` operator, it may mean *composition* so `z(x) = f(g(x))`, but definitely not multiplication of the results of invocation. On the other hand, the `lambda` above is very explicit, and frankly requires just a bit more characters to write.

---

*Update:* Kudos to JBernardo for hacking it together. I was imagining it would be much more hacky than in turned out. Still, **I would advise against using this in real code.**

Comment: Ahh yes, of course. I agree `f * g` looks ambiguous, so I'd rather use lambda anyway.

Comment: Not sure if lambda is any good in this case. Not that my answer doesn't use it, but it was just to prove it is possible. On your case you will just loose the function name (z) with no benefits. The `def` declaration is still better, I think.

Comment: @JBernardo: Why "loose the function name"? The function is attributed to the name z, just as if it was  def'ef. Unless you mean the internal `__name__` attribute - nout much of a loss anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I can be done with the exact syntax you intended (though using lambda might be better), by using a decorator. As stated, functions don't have operators defined for them, but objects can be made to be callable just like functions in Python -- 
So the decorator bellow just wraps the function in an object for which the multiplication for another function is defined:

```
class multipliable(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.func(*args, **kw)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        @multipliable
        def new_func(*args, **kw):
            return self.func(*args, **kw) * other(*args, **kw)
        return new_func

@multipliable
def x():
    return 2
```

(tested in Python 2 and Python 3)

```
def y():
    return 3

z = x * y
z()
```