# Repeating function n times printx

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function called printx() that just prints the letter "x". Then write a function called multiplex() which takes as argument an integer and prints as many times the letter "x" as the integer indicates by calling the function printx() that many times.

I already came up with this

```
def printx():
    print ("x")
printx()
```

But I do not know how to proceed, some help is appreciated;)

Any suggestions?

Comment: errr use a loop?

Comment: so your question is how to call a function n times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a function twice or more times consecutively in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047985/how-do-i-call-a-function-twice-or-more-times-consecutively-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

@Sjeng here is the code that you are looking for. Hope this helps you.

```
def printx():
    print('x')

def muliplex(num): # num is the number of times you want x to be printed
    for i in range(num):
        printx()
```

Comment: def printx():
    print('x')
printx()
def muliplex(8): # num is the number of times you want x to be printed
    for i in range(8):
printx()                     I did this, but still got an error message.

Comment: @Sjeng It works for me. Could you please send me the error message and if possible also a screenshot of your code? Would be glad to help you.