# Best way to handle data import paths independent of the PC I use

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am currently looking into working from different PCs on the same ownCloud data, doing file imports such as:

````
```data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\ownCloud\Sample Information\folder1\folder2\data.csv")```
````

However, only `"/Sample Information/folder1/folder2/data.csv"` is independent of the PC that I use.
The Jupyter notebook would be somewhere like this: `r"C:\Users\User\ownCloud\Simulations\folder1\folder2\data_model.ipynb"`
I tried stuff like the following, but it wouldn't work:

````
```data = pd.read_csv(".../Sample Information/folder1/folder2/data.csv")```
````

Is there a concise way of doing these imports or do I need to use the os module and some combination of `os.path.dirname( *... repeat for amount of subfolder until ownCloud is reached...* os.path.dirname(os.getcwd))` ?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

After some pointers I now use either of these solutions with v1 similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python) and v2 similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047985/how-do-i-call-a-function-twice-or-more-times-consecutively):

```
import os

ipynb_path = os.getcwd()
n_th_folder = 4

### Version 1 
split = ipynb_path.split(os.sep)[:-n_th_folder]
ownCloud_path = (os.sep).join(split)

### Version 2
ownCloud_path = ipynb_path
for _ in range(n_th_folder):
    ownCloud_path = os.path.dirname(ownCloud_path)
```

Comment: I don't think so there is a shortcut to do that without any imports. If you want me to tell you how to do that  using os module, let me know here.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace username in the path with its value by string interpolation.

```
import os

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\{}\ownCloud\Sample Information\folder1\folder2\data.csv".format(os.getlogin())
```

Comment: Hey, that idea is great and would fix my issue for some PCs. Unfortunately I also intend to use a linux system and the "ownCloud" folder has other names sometimes, eg "ownCloud_work". So I think everything before ```\Sample Information\...``` should be flexible

Comment: If it's flexible, where would you get this piece of information ? Do you want the users to set an environment variable ?

Comment: The way I thought about it so far is that I have my .pynb notebook which is n (quantity set by user in the script) folders inside the owncloud folder. So we would need to apply n-dots to the current work directory, or as it currently seems best to me, apply ```os.path.dirname``` n times.