# Higher order functions: automatic generation vs manual definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, implicit-conversion, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to delay evaluation for a bit, and so I prefer to work with functions as long as possible.

I have `class Function` which defines composition and pointwise arithmetics for functions:

```
from functools import reduce
def compose(*funcs):
    '''
    Compose a group of functions f1, f2, f3, ... into (f1(f2(f3(...))))
    '''
    result = reduce(lambda f, g: lambda *args, **kaargs: f(g(*args, **kaargs)), funcs))
    return Function(result)

class Function:
    ''' 
    >>> f = Function(lambda x : x**2)
    >>> g = Function(lambda x : x + 4)
    >>> h = f/g
    >>> h(6)
    3.6
    >>> (f + 1)(5)
    26
    >>> (2 * f)(3)
    18
    # >> means composition, but in the order opposite to the mathematical composition
    >>> (f >> g)(6) # g(f(6))
    40
    # | means apply function: x | f is the same as f(x)
    >>> 6 | f | g # g(f(6))
    40
    '''

    # implicit type conversion from a non-callable arg to a function that returns arg
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, Function):
            # would work without this special case, but I thought long chains
            # of nested functions are best avoided for performance reasons (??)
            self._func = arg._func
        elif callable(arg):
            self._func = arg
        else:
            self._func = lambda *args, **kwargs : arg

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(lhs, rhs):
        # implicit type conversions, to allow expressions like f + 1
        lhs = Function(lhs)
        rhs = Function(rhs)

        new_f = lambda *args, **kwargs: lhs(*args, **kwargs) + rhs(*args, **kwargs)
        return Function(new_f)

    # same for __sub__, __mul__, __truediv__, and their reflected versions
    # ...

    # function composition
    # similar to Haskell's ., but with reversed order
    def __rshift__(lhs, rhs):
        return compose(rhs, lhs)
    def __rrshift__(rhs, lhs):
        return compose(rhs, lhs)

    # function application
    # similar to Haskell's $, but with reversed order and left-associative
    def __or__(lhs, rhs):
        return rhs(lhs)
    def __ror__(rhs, lhs):
        return rhs(lhs)
```

Originally, all my functions had the same signature: they took as a single argument an instance of `class Data`, and returned a `float`. That said, my implementation of `Function` didn't depend on this signature.

Then I started to add various higher order functions. For example, I often need to create a bounded version of an existing function, so I wrote a function `cap_if`:

```
from operator import le
def cap_if(func, rhs):
    '''
    Input arguments:
      func: function that determines if constraint is violated
      rhs: Function(rhs) is the function to use if constraint is violated
    Output:
      function that
        takes as an argument function f, and
        returns a function with the same signature as f
    >>> f = Function(lambda x : x * 2)
    >>> 5 | (f | cap_if(le, 15))
    15
    >>> 10 | (f | cap_if(le, 15))
    20
    >>> 5 | (f | cap_if(le, lambda x : x ** 2))
    25
    >>> 1.5 | (f | cap_if(le, lambda x : x ** 2))
    3.0
    '''
    def transformation(original_f):
        def transformed_f(*args, **kwargs):
            lhs_value = original_f(*args, **kwargs)
            rhs_value = rhs(*args, **kwargs) if callable(rhs) else rhs
            if func(lhs_value, rhs_value):
                return rhs_value
            else:
                return lhs_value
        return Function(transformed_f)
    return Function(transformation)
```

Here's the problem. I now want to introduce functions that take a "vector" of `Data` instances, and return a "vector" of numbers. At first glance, I could have kept my existing framework unchanged. After all, if I implement a vector as, say, `numpy.array`, the vectors would support pointwise arithmetic, and so pointwise arithmetics on the functions would work as intended without any changes to the code above.

But the above code breaks on higher order functions such as `cap_if` (which is supposed to constrain each individual element in the vector). I see three options:

1. Create a new version of `cap_if`, say `vector_cap_if`, for the function on vectors. But then I'd need to do that for all other higher order functions, which feels undesirable. The advantage of this approach, though, is that I could in the future replace the implementation for those functions with, say, `numpy` functions for huge performance gains.
2. Implement functions that "raise" the type of a function from "number -> number" to "<function from Data to number> to <function from Data to number>", and from "number -> number" to "<function from vector of Data to number> to <function from vector of Data to number>". Let's call these functions `raise_to_data_function` and `raise_to_vector_function`. Then I can define `basic_cap_if` as a function on individual numbers (rather than a higher order function); I do the same for other similar helper functions I need. Then I use `raise_to_data_function(basic_cap_if)` instead of `cap_if` and `raise_to_vector_function(basic_cap_if)` instead of `cap_if_vector`. This approach would seem to be more elegant, in the sense that I only need to implement each basic function once. But it loses the possible performance gains I described above, and it also results in code that has a lot of function calls.
3. I could follow the approach in 2, but automatically apply `raise_to_data_function`, `raise_to_vector_function` functions whenever required, based on context. Presumably I can implement this inside the `__or__` method (function application): if it detects a function being passed to `simple_cap_if`, it would check the signature of the function being passed, and apply the appropriate `raise_to` function to the right hand side. (The signatures could be exposed for example by making functions with different signatures members of different subclasses of `Function`; or by having a designated method in `Function`). This would seem to be very hacky, since a lot of implicit type conversions may happen; but it does reduce the code clutter.

Am I missing a better approach, and/or some arguments for/against these ones?

Comment: Option number 2 sounds like a Functor's `fmap` (in Haskell) function to me; have you considered using a Functor?

Comment: I don't know what a `Functor` is, but I'll try to figure out. I suppose there's nothing that can be done about locking myself out of the major performance gains with this approach (I won't be able to use custom-made `numpy` functions that handle the whole vector at once)?

Comment: Tutorial(s) on Functors: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass and http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids -- And no, you will not be able to use the vector versions of functions if you go the Functor route :/

Comment: Btw, you have `rhs = Function(lhs)` in your `__add__` function, did you mean to put `rhs = Function(rhs)` ?

Comment: @paul thank you, typo in my code! And regarding vector versions: I suppose it's only an issue because python has an option of using the much faster vector library. It doesn't really come up in functional languages?

Comment: no problem :) I'm sure the issue does come up in functional languages, especially when using libraries like BLAS/LAPAK, but I've not done any performant computing in a functional language yet myself so I can't really say much on it.